# Plotting graphs on same figure with updated values

Tags: python, matplotlib, openai-gym

I am working with reinforcement learning envionments, for which I have an environment which simulates the charging process of a battery. With every step, the state of charge of the battery gets updated. I want to visualize this using a dynamic figure for all iterations.

Thre are options like pygame where the actions of agents can be visualised (for example the tic-tac-toe game). However in my case I simply want to plot a 2-d line graph which changes with evert run.

I am not sure how can I do this withmatplotlib.

I used the following code:

```
def _render_frame(self):
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # Create a figure
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)

        # First plot the action
        axes[0].stem(self._current_time_step, self._currnt_power)
        axes[0].set_title('Power output')
        axes[0].set_xlabel('Time step')
        axes[0].set_ylabel('Power (kW)')
        axes[0].set_xlim(0, self.total_timesteps)
        axes[0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, self.total_timesteps, 2), minor=True)
        axes[0].set_ylim(0, self._p_max)
        axes[0].grid(True)

        # Second plot the SoE
        axes[1].stem(self._current_time_step, self._agent_soe)
        axes[1].set_title('State of Energy')
        axes[1].set_xlabel('Time step')
        axes[1].set_ylabel('SoE (kWh)')
        axes[1].set_xlim(0, self.total_timesteps)
        axes[1].set_xticks(np.arange(0, self.total_timesteps, 2), minor=True)
        axes[1].set_ylim(0, self._target_soe)
        axes[1].grid(True)
        window_size = (800, 600)
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame with Matplotlib')
        #  Create a canvas to render the Matplotlib figure
        canvas = agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
        canvas.draw()
        renderer = canvas.get_renderer()

        # Fill screen with white color
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        # Get the renderer as a surface and blit it to the Pygame window
        raw_data = renderer.tostring_rgb()
        size = canvas.get_width_height()
        surf = pygame.image.fromstring(raw_data, size, "RGB")
        screen.blit(surf, (0, 0))
        self.clock.tick(10)
        # Update the display
        pygame.display.flip()
```

However with this code the figue is not rendered pretty (there are overlapped lines) and the transition is very fast that I cant see.

Comment: using pygame for this might be a lot more extra work for you and the machine than using something like `mpl.animation.FuncAnimation`. The key for your use case is likely to either clear the figure between frames, or to use the `line.set_data` trick from this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/strip_chart.html#oscilloscope

I recommend you try this task with `mpl.animation` tools before embedding it into a larger `pygame` based program, just so you can isolate your problem easier as you troubleshoot.

Comment: do you have to use `PyGame`? It could be simpler to plot without `PyGame`. And if you have to use `PyGame` then maybe it would be simpler to use [pygame.draw.lines](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines)

Comment: you don't have to create `screen` in every loop. It is like closing and opening again web browser to see next page.

Comment: if you want to slow down `PyGame` then you you can use ie. `self.clock.tick(30)` to keep `30 FPS` (`30 frames per second` which gives `~33 milliseconds` for every frame (`1000ms/30FPS`)

Comment: @furas I don't have to use Pygame; anything works for me. I just need to visualisation. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: if you want only display this plot then you could use `plt.show()` and it should create window with plot. If you need animation then `matplotlib` has `FuncAnimation` - [Animations using Matplotlib — Matplotlib 3.8.2 documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/index.html)